# Raphael.js Why my canvas size was not changed with browser window size changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, jquery-events

I would like to resize the width of my raphael canvas area according to the width changing of the browser window, but my code did not work as I expected. 
Following codes shows what I tried:

My ***index.html*** page:

```
<body>
  <div class="my-canvas">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myWin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myRaphaelApp.js"></script>
</body>
```

my CSS defined the initial size of my-canvas:

```
.my-canvas {

    width: 50%;
    height:800;

}
```

I have ***myWin.js*** which can get the width of the current browser window, and listen for the browser window size changing by invoking jQuery function `$(window).resize(...)`:

***myWin.js***

```
myWin = function(){


    var width=$('.my-canvas').width()*0.5;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        width=$('.my-canvas').width()*0.5; //update the width as browser window size is changing


    });



    return {
        getWidth: function(){
            $(window).resize();
            return width;
        }
        };
}();
```

Start to render raphael here:

***myRaphaelApp.js***

```
myRaphaelApp = function(){


    var width = myWin.getWidth(); //get the width of the current browser



    return {
        startRender: function(){


            paper = Raphael("graph", width, height); //width is not updated...
                        var c = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        };
}();
```

When I start my app in a small size browser window, the circle get drawn and the raphael canvas has the width of the initial browswer window * 0.5, then I maximize the browswer window, I was expecting that my raphael canvas width would be increasing as the browser window get maximizing, but canvas remain the same as initial size. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The Raphael code has no way of tracking the updated values of the "width" variable you maintain. When you initialize the graph, you pass in only a copy of the *current* value of "width".  Thereafter, Raphael has no contact with your code unless you explicitly updated in your own "resize()" handler.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not closing your `<div class="my-canvas">` tag.
2. You don't have a unit of measurement on your CSS height tag (e.g. px or em).
3. Unless your `width` variable is magic, you aren't updating the width of any element with your `$(window).resize` hook. You are merely setting the width variable to half the width of `<div class="my-canvas">`.

Answer (score 1):

Create your paper like this:

```
paper = Raphael("graph", "100%", "100%");
```